# Python substituir valores por outros em combinação

Tags: python, combinações

Opa meus feras, estou com uma dificuldade, fiz uma lista de combinação de 0 e 1, onde 1 será substituídos por valores positivos de uma lista, e 0 será substituídos por valores negativos de uma outra lista e somados com outra lista de números. (todas as listas tem 25 valores/colunas)

Eu já consegui substituir os valores positivos para quando tiver 1, mas não os valores negativos por 0, já tentei muita coisa e essa abaixo foi a minha ultima e mesmo assim nada. Se puderem me ajudar serei muito grato, abraços.

```py
  combina =  product([0, 1], repeat=25)

  for item in combina:
    res = sum([v + i*p + (not i)*n for i,v,p,n in zip(item, inicial, positivos, negativos)])
    print(res)
```

#### ATUALIZAÇÃO DETALHADA

Deixando o script desmontado na parte que estou tendo problemas:

```py
positivos = [0.0195, 0.0194, 0.0193, 0.0193, 0.0196, 0.0205, 0.0204, 0.0212, 0.0202, 0.0189, 0.0190, 0.0200, 0.0188, 0.0195, 0.0199, 0.0209, 0.0199, 0.0199, 0.0197, 0.019, 0.0201, 0.0197, 0.0196, 0.0189, 0.0194]

negativos = [-0.0298, -0.0298, -0.0300, -0.0300, -0.0297, -0.0288, -0.0289, -0.0281, -0.0291, -0.0304, -0.0303, -0.0293, -0.0305, -0.0298, -0.0294, -0.0283, -0.0294, -0.0294, -0.0296, -0.0302, -0.0292, -0.0296, -0.0297, -0.0304, -0.0298]


  combina =  product([0, 1], repeat=25)
  for item in combina:
    for i,p,n in zip(item, positivos, negativos):
      teste = i*p
      print(teste)
```

Printando o que somente a combinação, mostrará: (vou colocar apenas uma parte)

```py
0
1    # os valores que são 1, eu já consigo substituir pelo da lista positivos
0
0
0
0
0
```

Em ordem das listas, note que o numero positivo que mostra é o segundo valor da lista positivos, porque o primeiro é 0 (que teria que ser o primeiro negativo)

E teria que sair assim:

```py
-0.0298
0.0194
-0.0300
-0.0300
-0.0297
-0.0288
-0.0289
```

Mas logicamente teria que ser com base naquele primeiro código que mostrei, onde tudo esta em uma linha.

Comment: Junior, não entendi direito qual é o seu objetivo. Pode editar seu post com mais detalhes sobre esse problema que você está tentando resolver?

Comment: @AllanJuan Em qual parte não entendeu amigo?

Comment: Não entendi bem o que é que você está tentando fazer. Se você der um exemplo de entrada/saída demonstrando o que o programa deve fazer, acho que pode ficar mais claro

Comment: @AllanJuan atualizado

Comment: Elaborei uma resposta e, depois que vi os seus detalhes, decidir exclui-la. Outra coisa. mesmo com os detalhes que você adicionou ainda não entendi o foco da questão.

Comment: @Solkarped o foco é que os 0 não está saindo com os valores negativos, nos dois ultimos exemplos, compare eles, da para entender bem.

Comment: Junior, todo conjunto numérico possui valor `NULO` para a operação de adição. Se você estiver trabalhando com números inteiros o valore `NULO` será `0`. Se você estiver trabalhando com números reais o valor  `NULO` será `0.0`. Observe que `0` é um valor `NULO`, isto é, `0` nem é `positivo` e nem `negativo`.

Comment: @Solkarped entendi no que vc ainda ficou com duvida, atualizei o penultimo exemplo, da uma conferida, onde sai o valor 0.0194, é pq printando somente o "i", no lugar dele seria 1

Comment: Junior, o valor "0" NÃO POSSUI SINAL, nem positivo e nem negativo. ``0` é um valor `NULO`.

Comment: @Solkarped, eu sei, mas onde é zero eu quero substituir por um valor negativo, a lista de 0 e 1 que sai, é apenas para referencia de combinação

Comment: Então você deve criar uma restrição de modo que quando o valor for `<= 0` o resultado seja `0` e, caso contrário (valor `> 0`) o resultado seja `1`.

Comment: Por que você tem que lógicamente resolver esse problema em uma linha?

Comment: @LucasMaraal porque eu tenho outras funções abaixo depois, que pode influenciar no resultado, se essa linha for dividida em varios "for" e "if", mas se tiver alguma sugestão me diga que eu tento sem problemas, vai que não influencia

Comment: Eu primeiro criaria duas listas `p` e `n`, uma com os positivos e outra com os negativos e depois concatenaria as das utlizando `p + n`.  Por fim, faria a soma dos elementos desta nova lista criada com a outra lista que você cita.

Comment: @LucasMaraal boa vou tentar, coloca como resposta no post e com o script, assim movimenta o tópico e fica mais facil de ver.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se compreendi muito bem a pergunta mas segue uma possível solução.

Código:

```py
positivos = [0.0195, 0.0194, 0.0193, 0.0193, 0.0196, 0.0205, 0.0204, 0.0212, 0.0202, 0.0189, 0.0190, 0.0200, 0.0188, 0.0195, 0.0199, 0.0209, 0.0199, 0.0199, 0.0197, 0.019, 0.0201, 0.0197, 0.0196, 0.0189, 0.0194]

negativos = [-0.0298, -0.0298, -0.0300, -0.0300, -0.0297, -0.0288, -0.0289, -0.0281, -0.0291, -0.0304, -0.0303, -0.0293, -0.0305, -0.0298, -0.0294, -0.0283, -0.0294, -0.0294, -0.0296, -0.0302, -0.0292, -0.0296, -0.0297, -0.0304, -0.0298]

combina = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

combinada = [p if c > 0 else n for p, n, c in zip(positivos, negativos, combina)]
print(f'{combinada}')
```

Saída:

```py
[-0.0298, 0.0194, -0.03, -0.03, -0.0297, -0.0288, -0.0289, 0.0212, 0.0202, -0.0304, -0.0303, 0.02, 0.0188, -0.0298, 0.0199, -0.0283, 0.0199, 0.0199, -0.0296, -0.0302, 0.0201, -0.0296, 0.0196, 0.0189, -0.0298]
```

Dentro do zip colocamos as 3 listas iniciais, depois verificamos dentro da lista combina quais valores são maiores que zero e menores que zero, dessa forma nos possibilita preencher a nova lista com os valores corretos.

---

**Edit**

```
from itertools import product 

positivos = [0.0195, 0.0194, 0.0193, 0.0193, 0.0196, 0.0205, 0.0204, 0.0212, 0.0202, 0.0189]

negativos = [-0.0298, -0.0298, -0.0300, -0.0300, -0.0297, -0.0288, -0.0289, -0.0281, -0.0291, -0.0304]

combina = [ list(item) for item in  product([0, 1], repeat=10)]

combinada = [[p if i > 0 else n for p, n, i in zip(positivos, negativos, item)] for item in combina]
```

Coloquei apenas 10 elementos para teste(pois fica muito tempo computando se for um número maior), creio que funcione para os 25.

Comment: É tipo isso que preciso mano, só que o combina teria que ser todas as combinações possiveis de 0 e 1, por isso o combina =  product([0, 1], repeat=25), se vc executar, vai ver que chega a ser milhões de combinações possiveis, disso que preciso

Comment: Adicionei uma atualização na resposta, veja se é isso. Abraço!

Comment: Cara com 25 da o erro "Exception has occurred: MemoryError", até 15 roda certo, mas com 25 não da ;/

Comment: Mas isso é devido ao nível de complexidade da operação. Essa permutação é gigantesca possivelmente o pc está ficando sem espaço na memoria.

Comment: O que deve ser feito então?

Comment: A memoria do pc é limitada, geralmente para cálculos muito grandes a solução é ir salvando isso num banco de dados, num arquivo txt.

Comment: É porque esse valor 25, também corresponde as colunas do excel que ele irá escrever de A:Y

Comment: @JuniorLopes Com 25 vc terá um total de 33.554.432 combinações (mais de 33 milhões de listas, com 25 elementos cada). Levando em conta que um `float` ocupa cerca de 8 bytes (varia conforme a implementação, mas é mais ou menos isso), o programa vai precisar de **mais de 6 gigabytes** de memória (e nem estou considerando a memória adicional para a própria estrutura da lista, que também vai ocupar um espaço considerável, já que são 33 milhões de listas). Não tem como deixar tudo isso na memória, vc tem que ir salvando os resultados em algum lugar e não mantê-los em memória.

Comment: @JuniorLopes Com 15 funciona porque aí são só 32.768 combinações, que ocupa cerca de 6 megabytes (um pouco mais porque não contei a estrutura adicional das próprias listas, mas de qualquer forma, é bem mais tranquilo para manter em memória)